# Allow POST to "static" files on ASP.net development server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an issue where a service needs to POST to the root of my ASP.net application that is running in my Visual Studio development instance (/myapp/ for example).  However, ASP.net complains that "The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/myapp/' is not allowed.

How can I enable post to this path?  Would URL rewriting be better (rewirte /myapp/ to /myapp/Default.aspx)?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I was just able to provide a work around by adding this to my Global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string p = Request.Path;
  if (p.Equals("/myapp/")) {
    var query = "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString();
    if (query.Equals("?")) {
      query = "";
    }
    Context.RewritePath("/myapp/Default.aspx" + query);
  }
}
```

But I haven't tested this much and I am curious if there is a better solution.  This also won't work when deployed to IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for now.  It's a hard coded rewrite in the Global.asax file:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string p = Request.Path;
  if (p.Equals("/myapp/")) {
    var query = "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString();
    if (query.Equals("?")) {
      query = "";
    }
    Context.RewritePath("/myapp/Default.aspx" + query);
  }
}
```

I would love to see a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Url Rewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) module for IIS to rewrite the path.

The rule would look something like this (haven't tested it):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to Default.aspx">
      <match url="^myapp/+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/myapp/Default.aspx" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you but I am trying to get my VS development instance to handle the post. AFAIK it's far easier to get IIS to handle this.